# Defining Long Line like $\mathbb R \times [0,1)$ (cartesian product of real line with unit interval) instead of using ordinals?

Tags: general-topology, definition, real-numbers, ordinals

I was trying to understand the long line, and came across this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/apfzi/in_topology_the_long_line_or_alexandroff_line_is/, in which there's a comment that says:

> You're probably having difficulty because you need to understand
> ordinal numbers as well as standard run-of-the-mill topology.
> Basically, to make the long line, you don't label each interval with a
> real number, you label them with elements of ω₁, the first uncountable
> ordinal. The reals have the same cardinality as ω₁, but they are not
> the same ordinal; in particular, they do not have the same topology.
>
> Although if you did simply did take the Cartesian product of the real
> line with the unit interval, you could still define a similar linear
> topology on it by using the lexicographic order. You don't necessarily
> need to identify the "next" interval or ever actually glue anything,
> you just need to be able to define open sets using a total ordering.

Could someone shed more light on this last paragraph? If it's possible, I would like to see an alternative definition of the long line that does not mention ordinals at all but instead just uses real numbers.

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that $\Bbb R$ and $\omega_1$ have the same cardinality; this is called the "continuum hypothesis" and it's a very subtle matter.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}\times[0,1)$ with the lexicographic order does **not** give you the long line (for the same reason that the long line isn't homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Ok, so what about if we assume the CH and consider another order for $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s possible to define the long line without explicitly mentioning $\omega_1$ or using the continuum hypothesis, but it’s not possible to avoid using a well-ordered set that is order-isomorphic to $\omega_1$.

Let $\preceq$ be a well-order on $\Bbb R$, for each $x\in\Bbb R$ let $P_x=\{y\in\Bbb R:y\prec x\}$, and let $X=\{x\in\Bbb R:P_x\text{ is countable}\}$. Give $X\times[0,1)$ the lexicographic order with respect to $\preceq$ on $X$ and the usual order on $[0,1)$; then $X\times[0,1)$ with the linear order topology induced by that lexicographic order is the long line. This doesn’t explicitly mention $\omega_1$, but in fact $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$ is order-isomorphic to $\omega_1$ with its usual order, so $\omega_1$ is actually present implicitly — as in fact it must be in any construction of the long line.

Comment: well, although it's the same definition as the one using ordinals, this presentation makes things click better in my mind. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @D.R.: You’re welcome. There really isn’t any way to avoid the ordinals completely, because they’re inherent in the structure of the long line.

Comment: Sorry I had a question while revisiting this; why is $X$ uncountable?

Comment: @D.R.: First note that if $x\in X$ and $y\preceq x$, then $y\in X$. Now suppose that $X$ is countable. $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, so $\Bbb R\setminus X\ne\varnothing$ and therefore has a least element with respect to $\preceq$; let $y$ be this least element. The first observation implies that $X\subseteq P_y$, and the fact that $y$ is the $\preceq$-least element of $\Bbb R\setminus X$ implies that $P_y\subseteq X$, so $P_y=X$. But then $P_y$ is countable, so by definition $y\in X$, contradicting the choice of $y$. Thus, $X$ must be uncountable.